# iOS - Cannot access UITextView delegate inside a UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitextviewdelegate

I've found some problems when trying to access the `UITableViewDelegate` methods, inside an instantiated `UITableViewCell` class.

I'm trying to access the 
`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {}`
and the functions doesn't fire, and I guess that's because I've some issues trying to set the delegate.

The code goes as it follows:

```
import UIKit
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var postImageView: UIImageView!


    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        print("link tapped")
        return true
    }

    init() {
        super.init()
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

On the `super.init()` line this error is shown

> TableViewCell.swift - "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass" 'UITableViewCell'

Any tip on how to overpass this ?

Thanks in advance

**FINAL EDIT**
I've done what I really wanted to do.
Instead of using the UITextFieldDelegate inside the UITableViewCell Class, I've added the UITextFieldDelegate to the ViewController that uses the cell itself, and on the cell configuration just did:
`cell.textView.degelate = Self` , then I've implemented the delegate function of
`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {}`

Thanks for answering boys.

Comment: I've tried already with convenience init() and it didn't work

Comment: I don't think super.init() is a designated initializer. Try one of the others. I think there may be a super.init(nib:, bundle:) or something similar to that.

Comment: If I try the `super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "mainCell")` initialiser, the required init() fatal error is shown.

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to access object delegate properties inside table view cells, I'm missing something that I can't see :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textView.delegate = self
}
```

Nice work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, please provide some context surrounding your answer, and see the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on how to write great answers.

Comment: Strangely enough this worked, but I swear that I've tried this before and got compiling errors :/
Thank you anyway m8

Answer (score 1):

The line that's giving you trouble it not `textView.delegate = self` but rather `super.init()`. You'll need to properly call this with a nibName and bundle.

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: PutTheStringHere, bundle: PutTheBundleHere)
    textView.delegate = self
}
```